# mysql get the columns sum and also get the distinct values at a time

Tags: mysql

I have my data base like this

```
id   project_id    client_id    price

1       1           1               200
2       2           1               123
3       2           1               100
4       1           1               87
5       1           1               143
6       1           1               100
7       3           3               123
8       3           3               99  
9       4           3               86
10      4           3               43
11      4           3               145
12      4           3               155
```

Now here I want that it will sum the price columns with the same client_id.
For that I just made my query like this

```
Select  `project_id`, SUM(`price`) FROM `table-name` GROUP BY `client_id`
```

This one is doing sum the price but I am getting only two project_id in the result. I want the result should be all the distinct project for the client id and the price will be summed for the group clients.
So can someone tell me how to do this? Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable. Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question with the results that you do want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not have "bare" column in a `group by` query that are not in the `group by` statement.

If you want the list of projects, you can get them in a list like this:

```
SELECT client_id, GROUP_CONCAT(project_id), SUM(price)
FROM table-name
GROUP BY client_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

you only have two client that why you are getting only two record , you can group by two column,

```
Select  `project_id`, SUM(`price`) FROM `table-name` GROUP BY `client_id`, `project_id`
```